# Script in Unity responding incorrect values

Tags: c#, android, api, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have been trying to use weatherbit.io API to access AQI information in my android application. The script `AqiInfoScript` is used to access the API and the `Update AQI` script is used to print the value out.

**AqiInfoScript:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using SimpleJSON;

public class AqiInfoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float timer;
    public float minutesBetweenUpdate;
    private float latitude;
    private float longitude;
    private bool locationInitialized;
    public static string cityName;
    public static double currentAqi;

    private readonly string baseWeatherbitURL = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current/airquality?";
    private readonly string key = "*********************";

    public void Begin()
    {
        latitude = GPS.latitude;
        longitude = GPS.longitude;
        locationInitialized = true;

    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (locationInitialized)
        {
            if (timer <= 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(GetAqi());
                timer = minutesBetweenUpdate * 60;
            }
            else
            {
                timer -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator GetAqi()
    {
        string weatherbitURL = baseWeatherbitURL + "lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&key=" 
        + key;
        UnityWebRequest aqiInfoRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(weatherbitURL);

        yield return aqiInfoRequest.SendWebRequest();

        //error
        if (aqiInfoRequest.isNetworkError || aqiInfoRequest.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(aqiInfoRequest.error);
            yield break;
        }

        JSONNode aqiInfo = JSON.Parse(aqiInfoRequest.downloadHandler.text);

        cityName = aqiInfo["city_name"];
        currentAqi = aqiInfo["data"]["aqi"];
    }
}
```

**UpdateAQI Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UpdateAQI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text airquality;
    //public Text coordinates;

    private void Update()
    {
        airquality.text = "Current Aqi:  " + AqiInfoScript.currentAqi.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Current Output** : Current AQI: 0
**Desired Output**  : Current AQI: 129.0000

Comment: are you sure `Begin` is called? After `currentAqi = aqiInfo["data"]["aqi"];` Can you add `Debug.Log($"New data available: ${currentAqi}");` ? Did you also try explicitely call `agiInfo["data"]["aqi"].AsDouble` ? .. you also shouldn't post real keys here

Comment: In general I would not do this in `Update` but rather more event driven. Start next download after one has finished or failed. Only update the text componnet if new data was received

Comment: 1. Begin function was already present in the `GPS` script as `aqiInfoScript.Begin();`   2. I added Debug.Log     3. Also explicitly called `agiInfo["data"]["aqi"]`  ,  and all of them presented the same result as before    4. I'm sorry about the key, I have been struggling with this for quite some days now, I totally forgot about the key    5. Regarding your second query, I first wanted to make sure that I was actually getting the data before cleaning the code, but that is not happening even with the simplest of programs :(

Comment: But just to be sure that means it has nothing to do with your second script but the error already lies in the data you receive from the API ... are you 100% sure there is no typo in the keys for `currentAqi = aqiInfo["data"]["aqi"];`? Does the received json have **exact matching** field names? Could you show us the output of `Debug.Log(aqiInfoRequest.downloadHandler.text);` ?

Comment: The following is the link of weatherbit.io homepage which consists the sample JSON file `https://www.weatherbit.io/api/airquality-current#:~:text=This%20Air%20Quality%20API%20returns,(USA%20and%20EU%20only)`, I have checked this again and again. The `aqi` is under `data` class. No matching field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue

As I see it the API returns for [your request](https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current/airquality?lat=42&lon=-7&key=f732db7eede54da9bc383e983577c614) e.g. for `lat=42, lon=-7` the following JSON

```
{
    "data":[
               {
                   "mold_level":1,
                   "aqi":54,
                   "pm10":7.71189,
                   "co":298.738,
                   "o3":115.871,
                   "predominant_pollen_type":"Molds",
                   "so2":0.952743,
                   "pollen_level_tree":1,
                   "pollen_level_weed":1,
                   "no2":0.233282,
                   "pm25":6.7908,
                   "pollen_level_grass":1
               }
           ],
    "city_name":"Pías",
    "lon":-7,
    "timezone":"Europe\/Madrid",
    "lat":42,
    "country_code":"ES",
    "state_code":"55"
}
```

As you can see `"data"` is actually an **array**. You are treating it as a single value.

#### Behind the Scenes

Unfortunately the SmipleJson library you are using is quite error prone because it doesn't throw any exceptions for typos but rather silently fails and uses a default value.

You can see this e.g. in

```
public override JSONNode this[string aKey]
{
    get
    {
        if (m_Dict.ContainsKey(aKey))
            return m_Dict[aKey];
        else
            return new JSONLazyCreator(this, aKey);
    }
    ....
}
```

and

```
public static implicit operator double(JSONNode d)
{
    return (d == null) ? 0 : d.AsDouble;
}
```

#### Solution

It should rather be

```
cityName = aqiInfo["city_name"];
currentAqi = aqiInfo["data"][0]["aqi"].AsDouble;

Debug.Log($"cityName = {cityName}\ncurrentAqi = {currentAqi}");
```

---

In general I would suggest to use [`JsonUtility.FromJson`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html) and rather implement the required data structure in c# e.g.:

```
[Serializable]
public class Data   
{
    public int mold_level;
    public double aqi;
    public double pm10;
    public double co;
    public double o3;
    public string predominant_pollen_type;
    public double so2;
    public int pollen_level_tree;
    public int pollen_level_weed;
    public double no2;
    public double pm25;
    public int pollen_level_grass;
}

[Serializable]
public class Root    
{
    public List<Data> data;
    public string city_name;
    public int lon;
    public string timezone;
    public int lat;
    public string country_code;
    public string state_code;
}
```

and then you would use

```
var aqiInfo = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(aqiInfoRequest.downloadHandler.text);

cityName = aqiInfo.city_name;
currentAqi = aqiInfo.data[0].aqi;

Debug.Log($"cityName = {cityName}\ncurrentAqi = {currentAqi}");
```

---

For me as said with the dummy values `lat=42, lon=-7` both times it prints out as expected

```
cityName = Pías
currentAqi = 54
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<GetAqi>d__18:MoveNext() (at Assets/Example.cs:109)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

Comment: I used your exact `GetAqi` in an example script in `Start` and just hardcoded `lat=42;` and `lon=-7;` If I then do `Debug.Log($"cityName = {cityName}\ncurrentAqi = {currentAqi}");` I get the expected print .. no matter which of the two json libraries I use.

Comment: Thank you so much @derHugo . The application still returns `Current Aqi: 0` but now I will try the `JSONUtility` and implement it in that way. I have one doubt which may or may not be relevant here, but weatherbit.io has comething like **All parameters should be supplied to the Air Quality API as query string parameters.** , can this be a problem of some sort?

Comment: I am sorry to ask this, but what does 'in Start' mean? should I put my code in void start()? I am panicking at this point !

Comment: I used `Start` as this is called automatically on app start ... Just did it for testing .. if you say you are somewhere calling `Begin` then it should be fine ... do you at all get the debug log from the download routine? .. Possibly your routine is never started

Comment: Yes I am calling the `Begin` as soon as I get the lat/lon values from `GPS` script. I tested and found it accurately captures the lat/lon values. I'll try to put my `Coroutine` in the `Begin` itself, and see if it gets any better. No I don't get any debug files since I manually build APKs and send it to my phone. Any suggestions from your side? Maybe I should nuke the whole thing and start from the top.

Comment: Thank you @derHugo , problem was solved. You were correct, Coroutine wasn't being initiated. Thank you so much for your help!